# 1 validation error detected: Value at 'pipeline.stages.1.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to satisfy constraint:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-pipeline

1 validation error detected: Value at 'pipeline.stages.1.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 50000, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1] (Service: AWSCodePipeline; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: dd0be87b-8da9-4442-9d58-b3aad5f5ec33; Proxy: null)

I am getting this error , I have tried various ways to rectify this..I am not able to find the issue, My yaml file is below,

````
Parameters:

  SourceConnectionArn:
    Type: String
    Description: The ARN of the connection to the external source code repository
  RepositoryName:
    Type: String
    Description: dymocks-infra-data-platform
  RepositoryBranch:
    Type: String
    Description: main
    Default: main

Resources:

  CodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: InfraDymocks
      RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::515319848255:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-ap-southeast-2-dymocks_create_infra
      PipelineType: V2
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: codepipeline-ap-southeast-2-638430646560
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Checkout
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: !Ref RepositoryName
                BranchName:
                  Ref: RepositoryBranch
                OutputArtifactFormat: CODE_ZIP
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: Prepare
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                StackName: s3bucket
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
                TemplatePath: BuildOutput::create_s3_bucket.yml
                RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::515319848255:role/cloudFormationInfraRole```
````